# How to make the value of a custom CSS checkbox recognized in Edge?

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

I found a way to make a nice customize checkbox with CSS on [W3Schools here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp).

Now, on my site, I store their value in LocalStorage, and I retrieve it and have the box already checked when the user comes back to the site.
This works fine in Chrome, but I just realized it wasn't working in Edge.  After testing different things, it seems Edge can't read the value of the custom boxes (probably because the real checkboxes are hidden).  Also, when I try to set the the check with javascript, it doesn't do it.

See my code below.

```js
    function storeValues(lbl,answ)  
    {
      localStorage.setItem(lbl, answ);  
      return true;
    }
    
    const choices = localStorage.getItem('Ch2 myChoice1');
    switch (choices) {
     case "Yes":
      document.getElementById('Q1Answ1').checked = true; 
      break;
     case "No":
      document.getElementById('Q1Answ2').checked = true;
    }
```

```css
    /* Customize the label (the container) */
    .validationLabel {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Hide the browser's default radio button */
    .validationLabel input {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 0;
      width: 0;
    }
    
    /* Create a custom radio button */
    .blueradio {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: #eee;
      border: thin solid black;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
    .validationLabel:hover input ~ .blueradio {
      background-color: #fff;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px blue;
    }
    
    /* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
    .validationLabel input:checked ~ .blueradio {
      background-color: #292A5E;
    }
    
    /* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
    .blueradio:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }
    
    /* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
    .validationLabel input:checked ~ .blueradio:after {
      display: block;
    }
    
    /* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
    .validationLabel .blueradio:after {
      top: 6px;
      left: 6px;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: white;
    }
```

```html
    <form name="form2">
    <label class="validationLabel">Yes
      <input id="Q1Answ1" type="radio" name="Q1Answ" value="Yes">
      <span class="blueradio"></span>
    </label>
    
    <label class="validationLabel">No
      <input id="Q1Answ2" type="radio" name="Q1Answ" value="No">
      <span class="blueradio"></span>
    </label>     
    <br>
    
    
    <a class="send_button" onClick="storeValues('Ch2 myChoice1', document.form2.Q1Answ.value);">Send</a>      
    </form>
```

What's supposed to happen (and it works in Chrome) is upon first visit, the user makes a selection by clicking on YES or NO radio button.  When he later comes back, either YES or NO is already checked, depending on what he selected the first time.

Is there a way to fix this so it works on all modern browsers?
Thank you for your help, and sorry if I am not being clear or if I didn't write this properly, it's my first time asking for help on this site.

UPDATE: This problem happens even on a remote web server.  I am not testing the site locally.

Also, I don't know if it's related but the Edge console gives me this error:

> ```
> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json
> ```

Somehow I don't think it's related as that download link has to with cell phone emulation...

I uploaded the above code [here](http://impax.xyz/inf-5075/cssTest.html):

When I make a selection in Edge and click the button, and then check the localStorage (F12), it's undefined.

UPDATE:
Sending the string to localStorage work when I use the onClick event on the input button like this:

```
<label class="validationLabel">Yes
  <input id="Q1Answ1" type="radio" name="Q1Answ" value="Yes"  onClick="storeValues('Ch2 myChoice1', 'YES')">
  <span class="blueradio"></span>
</label>

<label class="validationLabel">No
  <input id="Q1Answ2" type="radio" name="Q1Answ" value="No" onClick="storeValues('Ch2 myChoice1', 'NO')">
  <span class="blueradio"></span>
</label>
```

But I still can't get Edge to set the radio button to CHECKED reading from the localStorage.  I know it reads it because when I add alert('choices') in my swtich code, it works.

Comment: the answer cited is old (2015) but apparently this is still a bug. Check https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8816771/, last comments are from 2019.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer, but no, I not accessing it locally but from a web server... Strange though misterManSam that it worked for you... I will edit my question in a bit to specify that fact. Thanks.

Comment: For a few minutes I thought my code was working after all, but I realized I was in Chrome. Lol. I tested on two different computers and the above code doesn't work on either using Edge. MisterManSam, I put a link in my question, when you follow that link and select either YES or NO, do you see that value under "Ch2 myChoice1" in the localstorage, or undefined?

Comment: @misterManSam Somebody changed my code in my question above and added the let localStorage part.  I thought maybe that was a suggested fix so I tried it, but no it makes it not work for everything now.  I removed it.
But I don't understand why it worked for you with Edge...  As I said I tried on two different computers...

Comment: @PatricFontaine They shouldn't have added or changed anything important like that. I rolled the edit back. It works in Edge, but I get undefined in IE 11.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK, I just did, or tried. Did I do it right?

Comment: Oh well, it seems the snippet gives a security error. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What's your Edge browser version? I have tested your code (using Edge 44.18362.1.0 version), it seems that both the check box and the local storage works well on my side, the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yk8o.png). Please refer to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to learn how to use local storage.